# How to use an array when transposing from long to wide format? Array subscript out of range error

Tags: sas, transpose

I'm trying to use an array to transpose a dataset from long to wide format. I would like to pull the form completion date for a repeating form into several columns so that each row will just have one participant, with all their forms on one row. Since I have to do this for several variables, I would like to avoid having to use proc transpose, so am trying to use an array to transform the data from long to wide format. I was following SAS' guide on using an array to transpose but am having trouble replicating it to my dataset. Specifically I am getting the error of "Array subscript out of range at line 39 column 4".

The following is my code that I am having trouble troubleshooting.

```
    proc sort data=bl out=longsrt;
    by pid;
    run;

    data wide;
        set longsrt;
        by pid;
    keep pid c10:;
    retain c10:;

    array ac10_formcompletedate{*} c10_formcompletedate;

    if first.pid then
    do;
        do i = 1 to 500;
            ac10_formcompletedate ( i ) = .;
        end;

    end;

    ac10_formcompletedate( redcap_event_name_bl ) = c10_formcompletedate;

    if last.pid then output;

    run;
```

Here's a small example of what my dataset looks like (For those familiar with REDCap, it is a REDCap export file):

```
data bl;
input pid redcap_event_name_bl c10_formcompletedate;
cards;
10001 baseline 2023-10-18
10001 baseline .
10001 baseline .
10001 baseline 2023-10-19
10002 baseline .
10002 baseline 2023-10-18
10002 baseline 2023-10-18
10003 baseline .
10003 baseline 2023-10-18
;
run;
```

Comment: Why not add an index for event and transpose using proc transpose instead? That way it's more dynamic and scales as your data does.

Comment: I'll have to proc transpose for several variables as this is across several forms each with several variables, so was trying to find an easier way than having several proc transpose blocks in one cleaner step, which is why I thought an array would be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how this should be done from start to finish, assuming I've guessed your output correctly.

```
data bl;
    infile cards truncover;
    input pid redcap_event_name_bl $ c10_formcompletedate : yymmdd10. status $;
    format c10_formcompletedate yymmddd10.;
    cards;
10001 baseline 2023-10-18 TESTA
10001 baseline .          
10001 baseline .
10001 baseline 2023-10-19 TESTB
10002 baseline .
10002 baseline 2023-10-18 TESTA
10002 baseline 2023-10-18 TESTB
10003 baseline .
10003 baseline 2023-10-18 TESTA
;
run;

*determine maximum size of array required;
proc sql noprint;
    select max(count) into :array_size TRIMMED from (select pid, count(*) as count 
        from bl group by pid);
quit;

%put &array_size;

data want;
    set bl;
    *by processing to control counter and output;
    by pid;
    format status_1-status_&array_size. $8.;
    *at first id set variables to missing and counter to 0;

    if first.pid then
        do;
            _counter=0;
            call missing(of c10_formcompletedate_1-c10_formcompletedate_&array_size.);
            call missing(of status_1-status_&array_size);
        end;
    *increment counter;
    _counter+1;
    *tell SAS to retain the values across the rwos;
    retain c10_formcompletedate_1-c10_formcompletedate_&array_size. status_1-status_&array_size.;
    *declare the arrays and sizes of the variables to be stored, max size was pre-computed;
    array _c10fcd(&array_size) 
        c10_formcompletedate_1-c10_formcompletedate_&array_size.;
    array _stat(&array_size) $ status_1-status_&array_size.;
    *assign values in row;
    _c10fcd(_counter)=c10_formcompletedate;
    _stat(_counter)=status;
    *output last value;

    if last.pid then
        output;
    *format data;
    format c10_formcompletedate_1-c10_formcompletedate_&array_size. yymmddd10.;
    *drop unncessary variables;
    drop c10_formcompletedate status _counter;
run;
```

Comment: this worked after some small tweaks to match my full data set! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You've defined the `ac10_formcompletedate` array with a single variable, so any index above one will be an error. Furthermore, the one variable you have in there already exists on the input & contains the data you want to transpose. Try `array ac10_formcompletedate {*} c10_formcompletedate1-c10_formcompletedate500;` or similar. You can also replace the code to set the array to missing with `call missing(of ac10_formcompletedate{*});` which will auto-scale to its dimension.

The second problem which you haven't hit yet is that you're using `redcap_event_name_bl` as an array index but the variable seems to be character. That's not going to work, and keep in mind that your array is currently indexed from 1 to 500. I could suggest something like:

```
by pid;
if first.pid then index = 0;
index + 1;

ac10_formcompletedate[index] = c10_formcompletedate;
if last.pid then output;
```

(this will still crash if there's more than 500 records within one `pid`)